How does "hot code replace" in Eclipse work and what restrictions or limitations are there in using this?
I work on debuggers, such as one for Python. My friends who use Eclipse to debug Java tell me that there is a very useful feature that Eclipse (and similar Java IDE's?) called "hot code replace" - if you edit a source file and save it while debugging a method, it will replace the (executing) code and restart the top most method.
I would like to be able to understand at a technical level a little bit about how this works, what the Java Runtime system provides to make this possible, and what restrictions or limitations there are for being able to do this.
For example, @howlger in the comments below informs that it "...only works when the class signature does not change; you cannot remove or add fields to existing classes, for instance."
Are there any other other restrictions?

This question is similar to: How can I set "hot code replace" when debugging python by pydev. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes, this is similar, but my focus here is more from a perspective of the Java runtime API that makes this happen. The other question is more from a more user perspective of someone who is using a tool and using features of a tool rather than using features of the Java or Python runtime and API.  I will reword the question.

that's almost certainly better asked on a dedicated java development mailing list or the like, since this isn't really a question about code you're trying to write, but is about the process that comes before that, where you don't know how to even get started writing any code. That said, it all starts with https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/jpda/architecture.html, which is a lot of reading, which is another reason this is probably off topic: the answer would basically be a lot of the documentation, rephrased.

Thanks for the link. Yes, it would be a lot of information to follow all of it, but most of that document is not relevant. I am asking about the back end interfaces (one of the four boxes mentioned)  that makes "hot code replace" work. What assumptions and so on. If this is too specialized information for most people who answer questions here, I am okay with this question hanging out for a while. I have found that eventually, someone who knows will see this and respond.

Yes.  This is way too complicated to explain in a StackOverflow question.  If you want to understand it, you will need to "do the hard yards" of reading the specs for yourself.  Another part of the picture is JVMTI - https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/jvmti.html.  (Or just do what normal people do.  Treat it as a black box and don't try to take the cover off.)

"What restrictions or assumptions are made?" - "...only works when the class signature does not change; you cannot remove or add fields to existing classes, for instance."

@howlger - thanks -this is useful information and the kind of thing I am interested in.

This is what I could find from wiki.eclipse.org and www.ibm.com, which boil down to not being able to change inner classes, method declarations and fields as well as methods called from native code on-the-fly as well as JSP debugging does not support it and it will not work on the bottom of the stack frame (i.e. the main method). But their description is much more informed than what I could provide, so here's my findings:
wiki.eclipse.org

HCR has been specifically added as a standard technique to Java to
facilitate experimental development and to foster iterative
trial-and-error coding. HCR only works when the class signature does
not change; you cannot remove or add fields to existing classes, for
instance. However, HCR can be used to change the body of a method. HCR
is reliably implemented only on 1.4.1 VMs and later, or using any
version of the IBM J9 VM. J9 is available in IBM products such as
Websphere Studio Device Developer.
If HCR does not work for you even in a simple Java application and you
have confirmed that you are running the application on a supported VM
(taking note that the JVM that runs Eclipse may not be the same as the
JVM that is running your Java application), you may not have automatic
building turned on. Make sure that 'Project > Build Automatically' is
checked.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace%3F
www.ibm.com
1

Hot Code Replace requires two things to work:
The VM has to support re-defining a class during debug
The debugger must be able to pop the frame that is affected to reload the class that gets re-defined. This is equivalent to the "Drop

to Frame" action from the Debug View.
One of the limitations with "Drop to Frame" is that the user cannot
drop to frames to a native method or any stackframes below the native
method. This is a limitation imposed by the VM. If you are trying hot
code replace on the first stackframe after a native call, it will fail
because the debugger cannot pop the frame to the native method and
reload the top stackframe.

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/understanding-one-limitation-hot-code-replace
2

Drop to frame and Hot code replace: Do not use the drop to frame and hot code replace features while debugging other languages called from Java™.
Changes to source that affect the shape of the class are not
supported. This means that changes to method bodies will be hot
replaced, while these are examples of changes that will not be hot
replaced:
changes to class structure, such as the removal/addition of methods
modification of class variables
changes to inner classes

If you change the shape of the class by adding or removing a field or
method, or as described above, you might receive an error with the
message "Scheme change not implemented", as pictured below:



This error indicates that you have performed an unsupported hot code
replacement, and the change was not processed by the virtual machine.
You might also see an "(out of synch)" message on the stack frames or
threads in the debug view. These messages should disappear if you undo
the unsupported change. Changes to the code in the bottom stack frame
(the main(...) method) cannot be hot replaced. Changes to the code
that is directly referenced by native methods cannot be hot replaced.
For example, imagine that the debugger is currently suspended in
methodA, called from methodB, and you make a change in the body of
methodA. The hot code replacement will not succeed if methodB is a
native method. You will not be able to replace methods invoked through
reflection while you are suspended in these methods. Some examples of
methods invoked through reflection, are constructors called through
Class.newInstance() and Method.invoke().
If you change the body of a method invoked by native code while the
debugger is suspended there, you might see an error dialog titled
"Obsolete Methods on the Stack" like the one below:



Continuing the previous example, since methodA has been changed, the
original methodA before the change is now obsolete. However, the
virtual machine is unable to execute the new methodA because it is
called from a native method, and so will continue to use the old, now
obsolete contents of methodA. JSP page debugging does not support hot
method replace of Java code.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/radfws/9.6.1?topic=debugger-java-mixed-language-debug-limitations

According to the docs, there is a "drop frame" command feature that allows one to go back up the call stack and rerun from there. I greatly appreciate your ability to take on a hard problem and summarize it despite others claiming it is too difficult to explain.

@rocky happy to help.
